# Java 7u25 Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: ssl, nginx, https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Im using nginx and have https(LetsEncrypt as CA) trafic, when I run my website in https://www.ssllabs.com/ I get the following result:

```
Java 6u45   No SNI 2    Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
Java 7u25   Server sent fatal alert: handshake_failure
Java 8u31   RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.2
```

Handshake fails when trying java 6 and 7 but works with java 8. Im trying to understand why it fails.. Does anyone have a good explanation?

I need to get this to work with java 7.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://superuser.com/questions/747377/enable-tls-1-1-and-1-2-for-clients-on-java-7

Comment: Is your website running in a a virtual host, where more than one website shares the same IP address?  If so, to access it via HTTPS, a client needs to use [SNI, or Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) to access your site.  Publicly-available versions of Java 6 do not support SNI. @Jens link shows what's likely the reason Java 7 failed to connect, but there are other possibilities, such as your website using only newer cipher suites that Java 7 doesn't support.